# Officially 5 days working but we work on many alternate Saturdays to get things done

Tags: new-job, job-change, job-offer, work-life-balance, india

I am planning to join a Indian Software Company. But I am not comfortable with working Saturdays.

How do I make them understand that I am not comfortable with Saturday's working.

I know, its not professional to agree to this point then simply flunk Saturday's anyway. Since its Officially off and they would pay me anyway(Well I am just assuming that they would pay).

**UPDATE:**
No I haven't signed any contract yet. I am looking forward to work with this company. The offer letter only has the designation and the salary. Other policies I will know while signing the offer letter. I had to ask them the basic policy and work culture in the mail.

Its approx 1 year old company.

Comment: What does your contract says?

Comment: They said they will show all the company policy while signing the offer letter. The offer letter which i received only has the salary and the designation of the work. I had to ask separately in the mail the basic work culture and policies.

Comment: i dont understand your title says something but you don't elaborate - 1. how do you know "officially 5 days working" (and what does it mean mon-fri??) is this in writing somewhere 2. how do you know many alternate Saturdays 3. I guess you are trying to seal the deal now with them (not signed anything yet) did you discuss your concern (i.e. "What are the working days?" ) of this with hiring manager??

Comment: @Brandin please check the updated info. I received a mail from them. Also read my previous comment for more info. Yes, mon to fri. The title is the line which was in the mail. Thanks.

Comment: No I mean still missing from Q is did you discuss anything, you know like in interview discuss "So, what are the working days of your company?" or something like that?? From your question read it theres not any background on why you think you are expected to work saturdays or whether you even mentioned that you would not like to work saturdays. That's important (what if working Saturdays is common in your region??) for discussion before taking an offer IMO

Comment: I had discussed with them, and they said its 5(I have it in written format). There is always "BUT" here in Indian Companies. Depending on the work, they call their employees on Saturdays too. And my question is how do I convince them to give me every Saturday off.

Comment: Is the second letter something you sign and return?  If so, I would add the clause "No Saturday or Sunday work unless I agree in advance, on a per-case basis."

Comment: So basically there is common policy of asking saturday work in general in ths region? Maybe somebody want to take a stab from experience but it seems maybe you have to discuss directly with them about your constraint. If you say point blank that you have prior obligations saturdays then later they unofficially try to recruit you for extra saturday work, at least you have a leg to stand on at that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prospective employer indicated to you that working days are Monday to Friday and that there may be exceptions.

You don't want to work Saturdays.

You have two options:

1. Tell them explicit do you don't want to work Saturday and you want this to appear in your contract. This will make it clear to them what you want and not want to do.
2. Tell them your are not keen on working Saturdays; Accept the offer and wait for the best.

As I see it, in the first case, you risk not getting the offer because sometimes the employer expect people to work Saturdays. In the second case, you will have to work some Saturdays.

This is the tough reality and I don't see how you can convince them to make an exception without saying it out specifically. If you are an exceptional individual they cannot succeed without, they may make an exception.

Young companies are often hectic environment with low staff count. Everybody is expected to pull their weight and take on all kind of responsibilities. Those companies are more fragile and working on Saturdays may be life or death for the company.

You can also ask them how you would be compensated if you are ask to work on Saturdays.

You have to ask yourself if you really want this job or not and what you are willing to sacrifice for it.

If you don't want to work Saturdays, you may want to pursue more established organizations.

Comment: In many locales (not sure about India, however), an employer cannot "expect people to work Saturdays" unless they're willing to pay them extra for their trouble.  Either at overtime rates or sometimes with time-off in lieu.

Comment: @aroth tried to include your concern in my answer.

Comment: i wonder why this happens btw. If it is every saturday I can undestand and plan for it but just randomly Work some Saturdays? It defies planning like what if you have weekend trip??